# Windows Form(C#):DataGridView System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datatable

I am getting error when i am delete record from datatable,The exception is below

```
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 10 does not have a value.   at
> System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32
> rowIndex)
```

I am using DataTable to fill the data and BindingSource to bind DataGridView, when i am deleting DataTable row record at that time above exception is occur, Below is my code

```
 DataTable journeyDataTable = new DataTable();
private void ReceivedMessage(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            var journeyBindingSource = new BindingSource();                                

            var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);

            switch (e.Topic)
            {
                case MqttTokens.JourneyHeaderInfo:
                    title = "Journey Header Info";
                    journeyDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { title, result });

                    break;
                case MqttTokens.JourneyDetail:
                    title = "Journey Detail Info";
                    journeyDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { title, result });
                    break;
                case MqttTokens.JourneyProgress:
                    title = "Journey Progress Info";
                    journeyDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { title, result });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //Add LogDetail
            infoLogger.Info(title + result);

            if (journeyDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                journeyBindingSource.DataSource = journeyDataTable;

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    grdJourneyInformation.DataSource = journeyBindingSource; 
                });
            }

            if (journeyDataTable.Rows.Count > 10)
            {
                var dataTableRow = journeyDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Reverse().Skip(10);
                if (dataTableRow.FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    dataTableRow.FirstOrDefault().Delete();
              }
        }
```

I tried with CurrencyManager referecing , removing data in thread, etc.. but same exception is occur

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The index is `0`-based, so if you're inside`if (journeyDataTable.Rows.Count > 10)`, then it will never be equal to `10` (or `9` for that matter ... `0` through `8`).

Comment: @roty.ap : Thanks for answer but what is resolution for this issue ? any idea i am not clear how to resolve

Comment: Change it to something 8 or less

Comment: @roty.ap:This is example but in my project its configurable... value is around 500